# How can I create a variable like newValue (used in setter) in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, getter-setter

All,

I have created a method which takes closure like this,

```
extension NSManagedObject{
    class func performOnWorkerContext(_ block:@escaping (_ context:NSManagedObjectContext?) -> ()){
        //Create context, Call block() and save context
    }
}
```

I use this method like this,('Request' is of type NSManagedObject). The class method will be modified to:

```
extension NSManagedObject{
    class func performOnWorkerContext(_ block: @escaping () ->()) {
        //Create context, Call block() and save context
    }
}

Request.performAndWaitOnWorkerContext { context in
    //Use the 'context' here    
}
```

Now, my question is how can I use this method like this,

```
Request.performAndWaitOnWorkerContext {    
    //Use 'context' here    
}
```

Here I want to use the variable 'context' (I dont know how to, which is the question). I have seen the similar implementation when we use setter in swift

Ex. If I use

```
var temp: Int {
    set { 
        print(newValue) // Here 'newValue' is automatically available
    }
    get {}
}
```

Something like this I want to implement, please suggest if its doable or not or how setters in swift do it?

The motivation behind this is it looks more elegant and we dont have to remember obvious variables accessible in this closure.

Comment: You can't. `newValue` in a setter method is a special case built into the language. (You can use short-hand a argument `$0` though.)

Comment: Don't be lazy, wiring `context in` is just 10 keystrokes.

Comment: Lol @Sweeper, true ... but sometimes I tend to :) in pursuit of neat good looking code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`newValue` is the default name of the parameter in the setter of 
a computed property, the `willSet` property observer, and the
setter of a subscript method. It is built into the language.

In a closure, you can name the parameter

```
Request.performAndWaitOnWorkerContext { context in
   // Use `context` here
}
```

or use shorthand parameter names:

```
Request.performAndWaitOnWorkerContext {
   // Use `$0` here
}
```

but you cannot define an implicit parameter name.

Comment: Interesting! I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is in general something you wish to avoid. In my opinion it would be better even in case of setters to have something like

```
set { newValue in
   _value = newValue
}
```

The main reason for this is that it is very easy to have conflicts in naming. Consider the following code:

```
let context = mainThreadContext
...

entity.performOnBackgroundContext { context in
    context.saveDatabase()
}
```

You can see that the 2 contexts are a bit in conflict and we may not use both of them. But in this case it is easy to simply rename one:

```
let context = mainThreadContext
...

entity.performOnBackgroundContext { backgroundContext in
    backgroundContext.saveDatabase()
    DispatchQueue.main.async { context.merge() }
}
```

While in your case if parameter is removed completely you don't have this power and more worrying is that someone else looking at this code will be completely confused that the two contexts in the following case are not the same object:

```
let context = mainThreadContext
...

entity.performOnBackgroundContext {
    context.saveDatabase()
}
```

On the lighter side I would try to completely remove `context` from the public interface and implement all the possible methods you need. So for instance:

```
entity.performOnBackgroundContext { context in
    entity.doMagic()
    context.saveDatabase()
}
```

would actually be:

```
entity.performOnBackgroundContext {
    entity.doMagic()
    entity.saveDatabase()
}
```

A bit of a warning though extending `NSManagedObject` or `NSManagedObjectContext` usually turns sour as complexity grows. There are better ways.